# what does the sentence "It is proving to be anything but" means

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading an [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/10/world/asia/indonesia-south-china-sea-military-buildup.html) in NYTimes and stumbled upon this line

It is proving to be anything but.

What does this actually mean?

Please feel free to read the article to get the context

Comment: It means, more or less, "It is not."

Comment: Please provide the context in the question. Questions should be complete in themselves (as should answers). Also, *anything but* is actually listed in [at least one dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anything_but).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[but](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/but)" means "except" here, and [proving](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prove) (in this context) means "to show a particular result after a period of time".

So if I say "It is proving to be anything but easy.", I mean "I've spent a significant amount of time trying to do this, and it's not easy.".  It doesn't necessarily mean that the person hasn't been able to do it, but there's a strong implication of that.